# Change a wordpress function name entirely

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress install in my system. I need to change the name of the function get_users() to get_userswordpress() across the wordpress codebase. How do I achieve this?

Comment: If you want to keep your sanity, that's impossible. If you explain your goal, maybe there are alternatives. Please, read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/185667)

Comment: I agree with brasofilo. Don't mess with the core code.